# Ajax error while saving a view

Tags: views, ajax

When I edit a view, and click on the "Save" button, I get the following message:

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
>   HTTP Result Code: 200
>   Debugging information follows.
>   Path: /admin/structure/views/view/vouchers_list/preview/page/ajax
>   StatusText: OK

What does that message mean? How can I fix the error?

Comment: refresh your page. it may be due to double request sent. also try jquery_update module.

Answer (score 2):

When you make a change to a view in the UI and click "save" before the preview has finished loading, you'll get this error. It's simply because you've made a 2nd request to the server while the ajax request to load the preview is still running.

You can either wait for the preview "loading" icon to finish before you save the view, or you can ignore it :)

Comment: I was getting this with Openlayers API IPGV&M in Views (on d7.30 running on localhost desktop), no idea, can't move forward,  An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 200
Debugging information follows.
Path: /websitename/admin/structure/views/ajax/display/asset_map_location/page/style_options
StatusText: OK